# Hausdorff Spaces Subsets open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

'Given a Hausdorff space $X$ with finitely many elements, show all subsets of $X$ are open in $X$.'

I let $U$ be an arbitrary subset of $X$

Since every subset of a Hausdorff space is a Hausdorff space, then $U$ is also Hausdorff.

This means that any two points in $U$ $x \ne y$ have disjoint neighbourhoods.

Does this imply every point of $U$ has a neighbourhood lying in $U$ hence prove open? This seems trivial. Where does finitely many elements come into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a finite Hausdorff $X=\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ space you can show that every singleton $\{x_i\}$ is open. Hence every subset is open since it is union of open sets.

To see that $\{x_i\}$ is open, we know that for every $j\neq i$, we have disjoint neighborhoods $U_j, V_j$ of $x_i, x_j$ respectively.

Take $$U = \bigcap_{j\neq i} U_j$$

Then $U = \{x_i\}$, which is open since it is *finite* intersection of open sets.

Comment: But if there are infinitely many elements of $X$, an infinite union of open sets is still open?

Comment: Right, but the fact that $X$ is finite plays a key role to show that the singletons are open.

Comment: Ohh okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Let $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. Given $x_i$, for $j\ne i$ let $U_{i,j}$ be an open neighborhood of $x_i$ that doesn't contain $x_j$. Then $U_i = \bigcap_{j\text{:  } j\ne i}U_{i,j}$ is a finite intersection open neighborhood of $x_i$ that contains no other $x_j$, so it's open. But $U_i = \{x_i\}$.

So all singletons $\{x_i\}$ are open. Every subset of $X$ is a union of singletons, so every subset is open.

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Comment: @jimbobeanz You're welcome. We all appreciate tips, ya know ;/

Answer (score 0):

We only need that singletons are closed (because then all finite sets are closed, and so all sets are open)...

Comment: But singletons are closed in $\Bbb R$ and yet the usual topology isn't discrete. Of course that works in this case, because $X$ is finite. Just that it might be confusing to OP..

Comment: @BrianO Yes, finiteness was used: complements of sets are all finite as well...

Comment: Sure, I realized that. I wasn't saying your proof had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest, here is a simpler solution to the question I asked.

We want to prove any subset $U$ in a Hausdorff space with finitely many elements is open.

If $X$ is Hausdorff, then by definition every finite subset of $X$ is closed. Take $X-U$. Since $X$ has finitely many elements, then so does $X-U$, which implies $X-U$ is closed. Therefore $U$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a finite topological space with a hausdorff topology. Observe that the topology must be discrete, and consequently, every subset is both, open and closed.